# Removing single quotes when retrieving data with php mysqli SELECT

Tags: php, select, expressionengine, single-quotes

I retrieve some database entries with php mysqli SELECT.

Some of the entries contain a single quote (ie : L'avant du bâtiment). This generates a parse error and breaks my webpage down.

Here is the query :

```
$themes = ee()->db->select('field_id_46')
    ->from('channel_data_field_46')
    ->get();

if ($themes->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach($themes->result_array() as $row)
    {
    $themesConcat = $row['field_id_46'];
    echo $themesConcat;
    }
}
```

How can I get rid of the quotes in the field_id_46 entries ?

Please note that the db Class belongs to the ExpressionEngine CMS core and that it should not be modified.

Comment: Where is it causing a parse error? It sounds like you're not properly escaping the data in whatever uses the result.

Comment: If you get rid of the quotes, it won't be the same French text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace()` function for character replacement.

The modified code as:

```
echo str_replace("'", "", $themesConcat);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Il worked. Thank you ! The problem was finally a bit différent than the one described above. But your info helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the character. You can do it with php's method addslashes like this:

```
echo addslashes($themesConcat);
```